# How do I give an inline image in a simplenews email an absolute url?

Tags: theming, 8, emails

The output from `field--text-with-summary.html.twig` gives each inline image a relative url of this form:

`<img alt="Image 1" data-entity-type="file" data-entity-uuid="5ed6da76..." 
src="/sites/default/files/inline-images/image1.jpeg" />`

These *inline* image tags are presumably generated by CKEditor; i.e. they are not *fields* with which I can use individual twig filters.

I have hacked replacing each relative url with an absolute one in the `items` array within the render array but these links are overwritten (somewhere) after preprocessing in the final rendering.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: There's an option core issue to solve this for any kind of link in an e-mail: https://www.drupal.org/node/2704597